# jquery mobile bottom icon navbar how to only reload page content

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jquery-mobile

I have an app where I use a navbar in a footer with icons. But when I navigate to other pages the content blinks or fadesIn. Is it possible with `jquery-mobile` to only refresh the content of the page without that blink?

Here is a [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/sylvanR/zhr27bud/6/) which recreates the problem.

So simply I have an footer like this:

```
<div data-role="footer" data-position="fixed" data-tap-toggle="false">
      <div data-role="navbar">
      <ul>
        <li><a href="#p1" data-icon="home">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="#p2" data-icon="arrow-r">Page Two</a></li>
        <li><a href="#p3" data-icon="search">Search</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
```

Which will navigate to these pages for example:

```
<div data-role="page" id="p2">
    <div  data-role="header" data-rel="back"><h1>Header Page 2</h1></div>    
    <div  data-role="content">
        <p>This is page2</p>
    </div>

     <div data-role="footer" data-position="fixed" data-tap-toggle="false">
      <div data-role="navbar">
      <ul>
        <li><a href="#p1" data-icon="home">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="#p2" data-icon="arrow-r">Page Two</a></li>
        <li><a href="#p3" data-icon="search">Search</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I allready found something like this but don't know if this is relevant or usefull: [LINK](http://scottwb.com/blog/2012/06/29/reload-the-same-page-without-blinking-on-jquery-mobile/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `data-transition="none"` for the links where you want to avoid transitions, inside the anchor tag. 
Your updated Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/zhr27bud/7/